# Fotorama Fullscreen

Tags: magento2, xml, fotorama

Is it possible to override the product image size declared in view.xml when you're in fotorama fullscreen mode in PDP? My goal is to change the image sizes when you're in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

you can update the forotama thumbnail size buy adding a setter in GalleryOptions.php in Magento_Catalog in getFSOptionsJson() to be exact.

As for the main image, the height is automatically calculated to fit the to the screen.